# CMD: IF Statements

Tags: command-line, windows-services, cmd

I need to executes different commands on different status of windows service.

example: (My windows service is OracleServiceXE)

if `OracleServiceXE` is `RUNNING` i want to execute command1

if `OracleServiceXE` is `STOPPED` i want to execute command2

i wrote below code for this. but it is not working properly. it executes commands in abc portion when `OracleServiceXE` is `RUNNING`

```
sc query "OracleServiceXE" | find /i "RUNNING"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 then GOTO abc
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 then GOTO bcd
:abc
echo aa 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 6000>nul
goto :EOF
:bcd
echo bb 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 12000>nul
```

what is the wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching with find, 0 is the return value when found, 1 is the return value when not found.
You can check that with `echo %errorlevel%` after the find command.
Also, `if ... then` is not cmd syntax (perhaps 4nt?).
So, it could be written:

```
sc query "OracleServiceXE" | find /i "RUNNING"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO stopped
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO running
```

Note also the order of `IF ERRORLEVEL` is important as `IF ERRORLEVEL n` means `IF ERRORLEVEL >= n`